# Checkout Headless Approach with Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Looking for a way to have a full checkout process with the Shopify Graphql API.
But the concept don't allow it? The final step is then always a redirect to the web checkout page from Shopify.

There are two ways so far I understood.

- via cart graphql api
- via checkout graphql API

**via Cart**

1. create Cart

```
mutation cartCreate {
  cartCreate {
    cart {
      # Cart fields
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

2. get checkout url and redirect user

```
query checkoutURL($cartId: ID!) {
  cart(id: $cartId) {
    checkoutUrl
  }
}
```

checkoutUrl -> webcheckout page

**via Checkout API**

1. create full checkout

```
mutation {
  checkoutCreate(input: {
    lineItems: [{ variantId: "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0VmFyaWFudC8xMzg3MDQ4MzI3NTc5OA==", quantity: 1 }]
  }) {
    checkout {
       id
       webUrl
       lineItems(first: 5) {
         edges {
           node {
             title
             quantity
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

2. redirect user again...
   https://shopify.dev/api/examples/checkout#complete-the-checkout

Extract documentation from shopify.dev.

```
    Use the webUrl field to redirect the customer to Shopify's web checkout form.

    Complete the checkout using one of the following methods:
        Shopify card vault
        Stripe
        Spreedly
```

webUrl -> webcheckout page

These are no real headless approaches.

1. Exists there any way to do real full cart -> checkout process without redirect to the shopify page?
2. Is there a way to transform cart to checkout? Don't understand for what it is then finally the checkout api needed, if I can't do a checkout via the api for the user.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out what to do here? I am also looking into this and am quite confused.

Comment: I think you have to actually checkout on the site that's why it's returning you a checkout URL, there is no other way.